# Is there a way to deactivate a Flexipage from the command line?

Tags: lightning, salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, flexipages

If you try to delete an active flexipage from the cli, you'll get the following error:

```
You can't delete an active Lightning page. Open the page in Lightning App Builder and click Activation to deactivate it. : Edit page in Lightning App Builder
```

Has anyone found a way to accomplish this via the command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- No, if you've set it as a default for an App or Org
- Yes, if you've only assigned the page based on app, record type, and
  profile.

The caveat above is because as soon you have a lightning page that is assigned as an org or app default, you have no mechanism in the Metadata API to remove it.

This is highlighted in the [CustomApplication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_customapplication.htm) metadata under `type`

> Required. Represents the type of action override. The valid values are
> Flexipage and Default. **A Flexipage AppActionOverride set to App
> Default can’t be deleted via Metadata API**. Instead, remove the
> override using the page assignment wizard in the Lightning App Builder
> UI.

Clicking on the `Activation` button provides the interface for removing the assignments for the Flexipage that live on other metadata types (Custom Object & Custom Application) when it's set as default.

If it's not set as default, you can just run the delete against the Flexipage (even if it has app -> record type -> profile assignments).